# how to change node name and copy data of that node in xml to another using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

My base XML is like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Report version="1.0">
  <sourceName Identification="xyz"/>
  <sourcesys Identification="mycomp">
    <Manager>
      <ManagerNo>1023114455</ManagerNo>
      <Address>Delhi,India</Address>
      <Currency>
        <CurrencyType>Rupee</CurrencyType>
      </Currency>
    </Manager>
    <Manager>
      <ManagerNo>236784455</ManagerNo>
      <Address>California,USA</Address>
      <Currency>
        <CurrencyType>Dollar</CurrencyType>
      </Currency>
    </Manager>
  </sourcesys>
</Report>
```

I want to convert this XML to the following one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ManagerDetails xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ManagerDetail>
    <ManagerNo>1023114455</ManagerNo>
    <Address>
      <PermenantAdd>California,USA</PermenantAdd>
    </Address>
    <CurrencyID>Rupee</CurrencyID>
  </ManagerDetail>
  <ManagerDetail>
    <ManagerNo>236784455</ManagerNo>
    <Address>
      <PermenantAdd>Delhi,India</PermenantAdd>
    </Address>
    <CurrencyID>Dollar</CurrencyID>
  </ManagerDetail>
</managerDetails>
```

Here is the mapping of the tags:

- sourcesys = managerDetails
- Manager = ManagerDetail
- ManagerNo = ManagerNo
- Address = PermenantAdd
- CurrencyType = CurrencyID

How would you do this with an XSLT?

Comment: Is your base XML definitely correct? The root element is **a1:Report** which means it is part of a namespace, but there is no namespace declaration showing, meaning it is not valid. Also, the **sourceName** element has no child elements in the base XML, but in the output, when it is transformed to **ManagerDetails** it does have child elements.

Comment: @TimC : sorry I forget to specify namespace a1:Report. you can consider that it is defined for time being. I am sorry about wrong mapping of SourceName . I have updated question please check. and please help me writing xslt as I am first time using xslt. totally new to xsl/xml/xslt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For transformations like this, you should be building upon the [identity template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) which by itself copies all the nodes in your XSLT

```
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
```

This means you only need to write templates for nodes you wish to transform (which, having said that, is all by the **ManagerNo** element).

To transform **sourcesys** (similarly for **Manager**), for example, you would do this

```
<xsl:template match="sourcesys">
   <ManagerDetails>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </ManagerDetails>
</xsl:template>
```

To remove an element, such as **sourceName** you would have a template that just ignores it

```
<xsl:template match="sourceName"/>
```

To handle **Address** this is slighty different, as you are needing to add a new element. In this case, I would write a template that matched its text node, and add an element there, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Address/text()">
   <PermenantAdd>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
   </PermenantAdd>
</xsl:template>
```

Finally, for **CurrencyType** into **CurrencyID**, this is straight-forward, but you would also need a template to skip over the parent **Currency** element, and process its children, like so:

```
<xsl:template match="Currency ">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sourcesys">
      <ManagerDetails>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </ManagerDetails>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Manager">
      <ManagerDetail>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </ManagerDetail>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="sourceName"/>

   <xsl:template match="Address/text()">
      <PermenantAdd>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </PermenantAdd>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Currency">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="CurrencyType">
      <CurrencyID>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </CurrencyID>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Also note there is a template `<xsl:template match="/*">` to skip over the root element, and it won't matter if it has a namespace or not.

EDIT: If you don't want to copy across attributes for **sourcesys**, but instead use new attributes, try replacing the template like so

```
   <xsl:template match="sourcesys">
      <ManagerDetails href="...">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
      </ManagerDetails>
   </xsl:template>
```

Notice how the **xsl:apply-templates** now lacks `@*` so it won't copy across any other attribute.

If you want

Comment: thank you so much for quick reply and giving brief explanation. I run your xslt but in <ManagerDetails> element XSLT is copying "Idenification" attribute of <sourcesys>. I don't want this attribute in <ManagerDetails>. Instead I want "href" attribute with some hardcoded value. I tried but not able to get it :(.

Comment: I've made an edit to the end of my answer to show this! If you have any more requirements that you don't know how to solve, it is probably best to ask a whole new question now this answer has been accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" standalone="yes" encoding="utf-8" version="1.0"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="ManagerDetails">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Report/sourcesys/Manager">
    <xsl:element name="ManagerDetail">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Report/sourcesys/Manager/ManagerNo">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Report/sourcesys/Manager/Address">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:element name="PermenantAdd">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/Report/sourcesys/Manager/Currency/CurrencyType">
    <xsl:element name="CurrencyID">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"></xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I really appriciate your solution. Its perfectly working as per my requirement. Thanks a lot for helping me guys :). If in future I like to remove full xpath given in match like **<xsl:template match="/Report/sourcesys/Manager/Address">** then how to do that?